# what to use as a bandage after lopping a tree branch

Tags: tree-care

What can be used to protect a tree when a branch has been cut off. I live in India and there are many boring insects that can damage a wound.

Comment: From what I have been reading, most trees have their own defense system. With that being said, I hear that a white latex paint with some water added is a good protective shield for trees. I am not a professional, just a person that has been reading a lot about fixing trees, as I have a Meyer lemon tree and it was producing beautiful lemon's until this year. I found that the leaves and branches were molding and the fruit this year was not good. So I started to prune the tree, when I was done, I realized that I had pruned way to much. Hence why I have been reading. I'm going to put a picture of

Answer (score 1):

"When proper pruning cuts are made (just beyond a branch collar at the branch’s point of attachment), healthy trees are genetically equipped to close the wound. Improper cuts from stubs or topping don’t heal as readily and may not be able to close. The exposed wood creates decay, entry points and pathways for pests, diseases and destructive organisms to move into and through the branches."
https://www.growingagreenerworld.com/tree-topping-what-you-dont-know-is-killing-your-trees/

[image]

If you cut the branch at the lateral ( the orange line) the branch is better left alone the tree will heal.
If it's cut wrong you need to recut it properly.

[image: This branch wasn't cut close enough to the trunk and ants killed it]
This branch wasn't cut close enough to the trunk and ants killed it